# Bad gateway on dataprep job run api

Tags: google-cloud-dataprep

previously same api was working fine but now it shows 502 bad gateway. Here is my api call:

```
def hit_dataprep_job(receipe_id):
    print(receipe_id)
    url = "https://api.clouddataprep.com/v4/jobGroups"
    body = json.dumps({"wrangledDataset": {"id": receipe_id}})
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json","Authorization": "Bearer "+str(key)}
    response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
    print(response)
    print(response.json())
    if response.json()['reason'] == 'JobStarted':
        print('started job successfully')
```

Output:
<Response [502]>
{'code': 13, 'message': 'BAD_GATEWAY', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo', 'stackEntries': [], 'detail': 'application'}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this incident is now resolved.  You can subscribe to https://status.trifacta.com/ for the latest update.

Join discussions and collaborations with Dataprep users in our Community, https://community.trifacta.com/s/.